# How to publish a R markdown document to be hosted on a server as a website securely (private) for a company without R-studio connect?

Tags: r, r-markdown

How to publish an R markdown document to be hosted on a server as a website securely (private) for a company without R-studio connect?

The link needs to be unchanged every time I re-run the R-markdown script to update the page. So that all employees can always use the same link to access the document. It also needs to be private and secure. Until now I have shared it through Microsoft Sharepoint but I have issues with the file link of the R markdown file changing from time to time, which means the new link has to be then re-distributed to all employees, which is a headache for everyone. Rpubs is good, but it is not private. R-studio connect is too expensive.

Anyone have a good idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you rerun the rmarkdown document locally, render to html and sync that to a web server. You control when it runs, it doesn't require shiny-server or Connect, and it's static.

Comment: @r2evans Yes I agree. What I need is a good option for server hosting and publishing that is both secure (private) and stable. I am thinking of Github pages.